# VS2012 Shortcut to goto matching Select Case from Case in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Does anybody know of a keyboard shortcut to use in VS2012, writing in VB.Net, to go from a Case statement up to it's enclosing/matching Select Case statement?